# How to reset the Microsoft Account password from a different Admin account

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, microsoft-account

I have following problem:

I have Windows 8.1 and few weeks ago I have created an user with faked microsoft account data. Now I have forgotten the password and I can not reset this password, because I used faked second e-mail for my data and faked names.

The same PC has an administrator account. How can I reset the password of the forgotten account?

I think, I have to change the Microsoft Account in a local account, but how? I don't see such option..

Comment: Settings -> Change PC Settings -> Switch to a local account -> Change your password

Comment: @techie007 I can not login in to my Microsoft Account, because I don't have the password. But I can login into my Admin account, but frome there I can not change the other Microsoft Account to local account

Comment: Have you tried going to https://login.live.com/ and resetting your account password there yet?

Comment: Yes. But it is impossible, because all data there was faked: Not a real name, not real address, not real second e-mail. So the question is: Can an Admin User, change an different User who uses a Microsoft Account to a local account.

Comment: Then you're probably screwed dude, give up and make a new account to use on that computer (local or otherwise). :)

Comment: No chance? What about transfere the installation to another account? I have some important programs there, which I don't get elsewhere

Comment: Nope, you're best bet is to just copy the user data you need out of that profile and then remove it.

Comment: @Sankp unless you installed them as an administrator the the programs only exist on that user which is a lesson for you always install programs so all users can access them

Answer (score 1):

From MS's page [What to do if you forget your Windows password](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/what-do-forget-windows-password#1TC=windows-8):

**If you've forgotten your Windows password, there are several ways to retrieve or reset it:**

- If your PC is on a domain, your system administrator must reset your password.
- If you're using a Microsoft account, you can reset your password online. For more info, go to the [Reset your password webpage](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=238656).
- If you're using a local account, use your password hint as a reminder.

**If you've tried these suggestions and still can't sign in:**

- If you have Windows 8.1, you'll need to reinstall Windows.
- If you have Windows RT 8.1, you'll need to contact your PC manufacturer.